# Установка срока действия пароля в Django

Tags: django

В Django я использую метод авторизации **django-allauth**
В документации по Django я не нашел информации по настройке срока действия пароля для пользователей.
Существует ли готовое решение в django-allauth по установке срока действия пароля например 90 дней? Если есть, то как называется этот параметр и где его нужно указать, так же нужно если этот пароль истек, перенаправить пользователя на форму смены пароля.
Спасибо.